# Binding `Transformable` object in SUBQUERY changes it's bound value in a predicate for a NSFetchRequest for CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've got a set-up in CoreData with the following relations: (`>> to-many, > to-one`)

`Role <->> Access <<-> AccessGroup <<->> Application`

Both `Role` and `Application` has `id`, which is a `Transformable` attribute. Thus it's stored as `blob` in the database.

When I should perform a fetch request to find all `Access`s that has access to an application with a specific `id`, I'll do the following:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Access> = Access.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
    NSPredicate(format: "ANY accessGroup.applications.id == %@", applicationId)
])
```

Everything seems to work fine, and when I inspect the output after running it with `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` I see the following:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT DISTINCT t0.Z_ENT, .. much stuff .. WHERE (( t3.ZID = ? AND  t4.ZID = ?) AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?)  LIMIT 1
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = <NSData len=22>
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = 2
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0006s
```

As you can see, `bind[0]` is `NSData`, which I'd expect it to be. Since it will take my custom class and transform it to `NSData` using the ValueTransformer I've defined.

However, when I should perform a fetch request to find all `Role`s that has access to an application with a specific `id`, I can't use `"ANY accesses.accessGroup.applications.id == %@", applicationId)` because that gives me `multiple to-many keys not allowed here`. So then I wrote it using a `SUBQUERY` instead, like below:

```
NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(accesses, $access, ANY $access.accessGroup.applications.id == %@).@count > 0", application.id)
```

And when we inspect this output instead, you'll see that `bind[0]` is written out as if it's a string instead. It's not written as `NSData`.

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT DISTINCT ... much stuff ... AND ( t4.ZID = ?)) ) > ? AND  t0.Z_ENT >= ? AND  t0.Z_ENT <= ?) 
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = abc.def
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = 0
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = 3
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[3] = 5
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0005s
```

I think this is the error, and the I presume it's an error in the framework, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: To clarify, both `applicationId` and `application.id` are of the same type. Which is the custom type that implements `ValueTransformer`, which is named like `MyCustomId`.

Comment: In the second case, the variable passed into the predicate format string is `application.id`, in the first case it’s `applicationId`.  Does the problem lie in that difference?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I've clarified in the question that both of them are of the same type